# Stop body from scrolling on safari iOS 15

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, mobile-safari

I have a scrollable page and a drawer. When the drawer is open (which is not scrollable) I noticed that when I do a scroll touch - from bottom to top or top to bottom, the safari url/search bar appears/disappears and this breaks my layout. I tried having `overflow:hidden` and `touch-action:none` on body when the drawer is open, but this doesn't work on Safari. The only solution I found is setting the html overflow to hidden, but this makes the page behind the drawer to reset the scrolling position (0,0).
Is there any solution to keep the current scroll position while disabling this annoying effect?

Comment: Can you post your code so we can understand your question better?

Comment: It's the antd drawer. https://ant.design/components/drawer/
The way it works is that when it's open, they add a class to body with overflow:hidden and touch-action:none. I use something like document.documentElement.style.setProperty('overflow', 'hidden') as a temporary fix to set the HTML overflow to hidden